# CSS fake HR with background image

Tags: css

I want to have a HR like background image. a 2 pixel wide gif file.
I looked into styling the HR tag, but too much browser issues..

Used a 2px high div with the image as bg, but in IE6, there is a padding I can not seem to get rid of.
Any suggestions welcome!

CSS:

```
.hr {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-image: url('images/help-hr.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: green; /* just to see the padding in IE6 */
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>sky</p>
<div class="hr"></div>
<p>grass</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add overflow:hidden;

```
.hr {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;    
    height: 2px;    
    background-image: url('images/help-hr.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: green; /* just to see the padding in IE6 */

    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer to the IE6 issue you're dealing with, but I had the same issue with using `hr` and [found a solution](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-hr-styling/) that worked for me:

```
hr {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 0;
  color: #ccc;
  height: 2px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: -.5em 10px 1.8571em 10px;
  page-break-after: always;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

hr:after {
  content: "\a7\a7";
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for the HR styling and reference. I prefer a background image though.